# Tweeting from iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I have an application with one `UILabel` and one `UIButton`.
How can I send the text in the `UILabel` to Twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in iOs 5 it is very simple.

first add the twitter framework der `Build Phases / Link Binary With Libraries`
[image: Build Phases / Link Binary With Libraries]

```
- (IBAction)yourTweetUIButtonAction:(id)sender {    
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = 
            [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweet setInitialText:yourUILabel.text];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
    } else {
        //can't tweet!
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ShareKit:
http://getsharekit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code that all you need:

```
-(IBAction)postTwitter:(id)sender {

SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

     [tweetSheet setInitialText:yourlabel.text];
     [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```