# How to post in twitter with ios5?

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to post my Game score and image in twitter...How to post the image and text in twitter with the new Twitter API ??

Please anyone help with this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tweeting from iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257627/tweeting-from-ios-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code below:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweeter setInitialText:@"message"];
        [tweeter addImage:image];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];
```